# How to triggle popover on select option change event in Boostrap 5 popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a select box with 4 options and when I click on the select option and then on the change event of select, triggers the bootstrap 5 popover dyamic.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mayursutariya93/qjeg5r9b/6/

HTML:

```
<select class="form-select">
  <option selected disabled>All Locations</option>
  <option value="01">001</option>
  <option value="02">002</option>
  <option value="03">003</option>
  <option value="04">004</option>
</select>
```

Basically created a select option box and popover.

```
<div class="about-location-list">
  <a tabindex="0" class="about-location-list-item" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" data-bs-title="Title 01" data-bs-content='<span>Lorim ipsum 01</span>'>Title 01</a>
  <a tabindex="1" class="about-location-list-item" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" data-bs-title="Title 02" data-bs-content='<span>Lorim ipsum 01</span>'>Title 02</a>
  <a tabindex="2" class="about-location-list-item" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" data-bs-title="Title 03" data-bs-content='<span>Lorim ipsum 01</span>'>Title 03</a>
  <a tabindex="3" class="about-location-list-item" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" data-bs-title="Title 04" data-bs-content='<span>Lorim ipsum 01</span>'>Title 04</a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const popoverTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]')
const popoverList = [...popoverTriggerList].map(popoverTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl))
```

Call the popover function.

Answer (score 0):

Which one of the links do you want to popover? I did them all.

Here's how to `show` a popover manually.

```js
document.querySelector('.form-select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var value = this.value
  console.log(value);

  var elem = document.querySelectorAll('.about-location-list a')[+value-1]
  const popover = bootstrap.Popover.getOrCreateInstance(elem)
  popover.show();
  // console.log("inner" + index + value);

})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-select">
  <option selected disabled>All Locations</option>
  <option value="01">001</option>
  <option value="02">002</option>
  <option value="03">003</option>
  <option value="04">004</option>
</select>


<div class="about-location-list">
  <a tabindex="0" class="about-location-list-item" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" data-bs-title="Title 01" data-bs-content='<span>Lorim ipsum 01</span>'>Title 01</a>
  <a tabindex="1" class="about-location-list-item" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" data-bs-title="Title 02" data-bs-content='<span>Lorim ipsum 01</span>'>Title 02</a>
  <a tabindex="2" class="about-location-list-item" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" data-bs-title="Title 03" data-bs-content='<span>Lorim ipsum 01</span>'>Title 03</a>
  <a tabindex="3" class="about-location-list-item" role="button" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-html="true" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-trigger="focus" data-bs-custom-class="custom-popover" data-bs-title="Title 04" data-bs-content='<span>Lorim ipsum 01</span>'>Title 04</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for only popover visible when select particular option. e.g If I select 2nd option then 2nd popover visible, not others. Thanks.